# How can I assign different data-attributes to cloned DOM elements with jQuery .clone()

Tags: jquery, html

Using `$("#set .item").clone().appendTo(".container")` I can clone:

```
<div style='display:none' id='set'>
    <div class='item' >
        <img class='avatar' src="http://placekitten.com/80/80" />
        <div class='box' data-id='foo'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And append it to a container.

Of course `clone` creates a copy of `#set .item` so if I clone and append multiple objects:

```
for( var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    $("#set .item").clone().appendTo(".container");
}
```

How can I assign different `data-` attributes to each clone?

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kRS5s/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var cln = $("#set .item").clone();
        cln.find('.box').attr('data-id', 'foo_' + i);
        cln.appendTo(".container");
    }
    $('.item .box').text(function(){return $(this).attr('data-id')});
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tYL6d/)

If you want to use a oneliner use this:

```
$("#set .item").clone().find('.box').attr('data-id', 'foo_' + i).end().appendTo(".container");
```

jQuery has also a special method for this. Read more [**here about .data()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Answer (score 0):

Well you simply do something like this.

```
for( var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    $("#set .item").clone().attr('clone-id', i).appendTo(".container");
}
```